# How do I show a div just on homepage after scrolling 800 px?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, header, hide

I need to hide my header just on the homepage until I scroll to `800px` from top; after `800px` from the top I need to have my floating menu reappearing just right after the banner.

This is my wordpress website `psao.co.uk` for your reference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use element.scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries for this sort of interaction. 
[ScrollMagic](https://scrollmagic.io/) for example.